# Nightlife in Russia

Tags: safety, russia, nightlife, moscow, saint-petersburg

Does nightlife exist in Russia (Moscow, St. Petersburg)?
Overall, is it safe to be out at nights as a foreigner?
Is it safe to participate in nightclubs?

Comment: What are you considering comparable for "safe"?

Comment: And what do you consider a nightlife?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have been to night clubs in Moscow, although last time a few years ago, so this relates to my own experience.  Note that Russian is one of my native languages, therefore I didn't have to deal with the language problem (although I am not native Russian).

It's often very difficult to get into very "high class" clubs, although not impossible.  If you don't speak the language, then I strongly recommend going with somebody that does.  Also, many clubs wouldn't let single men in and often single women either (as an example, in Moscow I went out with my girlfriend and her sister; one of the clubs we tried getting into was happy to let me and my girlfriend in, but not my gf's sister - stating that I could go in with only one of the girls).  With slightly lower level clubs, you should have no problem getting in.  They are just as safe as clubs in any other large city.

If you go to clubs that specifically cater to foreigners, then pretty much all staff will speak English (and often French as well).  In other clubs, it's rather unlikely.

Safety wise, your major concerns should be around being on the street in the wrong part of town.  Not so much in the city centre, but farther out, and even in small side streets in city centre, you may encounter hooligans that could spoil your night out.  Yet, if you stick to major areas in the centre, you'll be fine.

All in all, you should be perfectly safe. Have fun - and enjoy Russia!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it does exists :) As I can say, night life in Moscow is much more glamourous, rather than in Saint-Petersburg there are a lot of small clubs, each with a small dance hall (there are big ones also, but not in such number as in Moscow).

Many of them are located across Nevsky prospekt, so pick and go there :)

One should note that the right company will help you to enjoy the night, as they can help with language barrier and with your choice. As we are talking about the night clubs, stakes are high that you'll find there an English-speaking person, but I suggest you not to come alone.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer, I've never been to Russia, and only been clubbing (before and afterhours) in London, Paris, Barcelona and my hometown Montreal).

I do believe that clubbing in Russia is safe, at least for the major clubs that attracts international DJs.

See your previous post about language issue in Russia.

If you feel that language is an issue during the day in normal circumstances, it will be exacerbated at night in a clubbing environment; do not put yourself in situation where your safety can be compromised.

Remember that in a club environment anywhere, there are a lot of factors that can become safety issues, one is alcohol and drugs and the other is everything related to sex and/or flirting (with the wrong person)

Other than that, have fun.

Comment: Given that the question is about Russia and you state you have never been there, what makes your belief worth a thought?

Answer (score 1):

I've been in St.Petersburg last year in march, it's quite soggy, wether isn't friendly for long walks through the city in this time of the year.. But I can say if u r looking for a nightlife, St.Petersburg is really suitable for it. there are a lot of cozy bars with local and european beer, and, of course, vodka:) I strongly recommend to visit Siniy Pushkin (good music, shots, friendly service), pub Arka with great-great-great food and cocktail-menu, Sidreria on Mokhovaya (smth like that) with huge choice of beer and cider and really friendly waitresses) for those, who prefer smth more exotic, I can recommend strip bar Zavist, full of hot girls who kindly serve you with drinks on their bodies:) I can say that I travelled alone and I didn't have any problems with safety, moreover, I went out each evening and everytime I managed to find a friendly company)I think it's just strong stereotype, which has come from 90s, that Russia is totally unsafe place.. After my experience I can say, that it's not true at all. Enjoy your stay in St.Petersburg!